# Semi automated dictionary application

Tags: spanish, dictionary

I asked this question on stackoverflow, and got put [on hold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191599/semi-automated-dictionary-application-human-language); rightfully so. I hope this is a better place.

*Are there applications, desktop applications, plugins, libraries, etc., dedicated to removing the drudgery of copy/pasting from accessing your favorite online dictionary? So you can merely click once on a word in your pdf and instantly see the relevant definition; dismiss it easily, too.*

*It would be a great help in studying foreign languages; somebody must have thought of that already :)*

I am particularly interested in Spanish-English dictionaries. I am also a programmer, so links on something highly technical are welcome, too.

Comment: What is your target platform? For instance, there is a lot of add-ons for Firefox/Chrome for PC; Dictionary Anywhere, Dictionarist, English Popup Dictionary, Quick Dictionary, to name a few.

Comment: Goldendict has a pop-up option that will do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use macOS or iPhone. Just tap on the word and you can see its definition.

[image]

You can select which language to use from the built-in Dictionary app.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this exists for Sami, Kven, and some other languages, over here: https://sanit.oahpa.no/read/ . It seems to be a bookmarklet or something to be installed to a web page; I do not know whether it works with a PDF.

The list of supported languages is at https://sanit.oahpa.no/more/ . Most of them are Finno-Ugric. It seems possible to add more languages, but it might be a demanding task.